# Google app scripts: How to set date format on horizontal axis chart on Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a chart from data on spreadsheet, but I have troubles managing the format on horizontal axis on the new created chart.

I've tried to utilice the method "setOption('vAxis.format', 'dd/MM/YY')" but it doesn't work, showing the ticks labels like "dd/MM/YY 00:00:00": [Figure 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D3ZS9P3adxY1lqqkmk2jQFpq5j-0MRX9/view?usp=sharing)

If I change the date format on the spreadsheet so i get a deformed values on second chart: [Figure 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jCxtJp1R0449RS4s4CmGURyPrvVVdAWg/view)

The spreadsheet: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lVqL5nT1IS3T2LPrcB5QAg_03ni0JgoJ-gxbAWdWb0I/edit#gid=1595390300)

Google script code:

```
function Test_format_chart() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lVqL5nT1IS3T2LPrcB5QAg_03ni0JgoJgxbAWdWb0I")
var sh=ss.getSheetByName("TestSheet");
var chts=sh.getCharts();

 for(var i=0;i<chts.length;i++) {
   sh.removeChart(chts[i]);
 }
var chartBuilder = sh.newChart();
chartBuilder.addRange(sh.getRange("A1:B25"))
.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
.setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true) 
.setPosition(2, 4, 0, 0)
.setOption('title', 'My Line Chart!')
.setOption('hAxis.textStyle',{color:'#ff0000'})
.setOption('hAxis.format', 'dd/MM/YY')
sh.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());  
}
```

Keep in mind that the previous code is only a simplicated view of original implementation. In the original project we export  the second chart in an e-mail, but the problem that we see is the same. Thanks!

--

27/09/2019 update:

I'm trying a new strategy, using unixtime format date on the column, and later try to replace the value on horizontal axis with a literal string as the [line chart documentatión](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) shows on the 'hAxis.ticks' option. But I'm not obtaining the expected results, the horizontal ticks labels doesn't change with the setOption('hAxis.ticks',....) variations I'm traying.

Some code:

```
function Test_format_chart() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lVqL5nT1IS3T2LPrcB5QAg_03ni0JgoJgxbAWdWb0I")     
var sh=ss.getSheetByName("TestSheet");
var chts=sh.getCharts();

 for(var i=0;i<chts.length;i++) {
   sh.removeChart(chts[i]);
 }

 var chartBuilder = sh.newChart();
 chartBuilder.addRange(sh.getRange("A1:B25"))
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true) 
  .setPosition(2, 4, 0, 0)
  .setOption('title', 'My Line Chart!')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle',{color:'#ff0000'})
  .setOption('hAxis.ticks', [1568023200, 156802324900])// <--

  sh.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a work around.  I couldn't find any other way to do it than to just change the numberFormat for the date column in your sheet.

```
function Test_format_chart() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lVqL5nT1IS3T2LPrcB5QAg_03ni0JgoJgxbAWdWb0I")
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("TestSheet");
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yy");//Modify the format for column one date data.
  var chart=sh.getCharts()[0].modify()
  .setPosition(5,10,0,0)
  .setOption('title', 'Formated new chart')
  .build();
  sh.updateChart(chart); 
}
```

[Class Embedded Chart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart.html)

This is the script I've been using to do my testing for last couple of hours:

```
function createChart() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg= sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var drg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yy");
  var chts=sh.getCharts();
  for(var i=0;i<chts.length;i++) {
    sh.removeChart(chts[i]);
  }
  var chartBuilder = sh.newChart();
  chartBuilder.addRange(rg)
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
  .setPosition(2, 4, 0, 0)
  .setOption('title', 'My Line Chart!')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle',{color:'#ff0000'});
  sh.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
}
```

This is what my Sheet1 looks like:

[image]

> Notice that it changes the formatting of the date column

This is probably not what you wanted.  Sorry.

Comment: Cooper, Thank you for your reply. I've tried your suggestion but the
"00:00:00" still on the horizontal ticks label after the dd/MM/YY. [Look](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CXPmxR6f1RcyfzGjYA7P3iBBygzy6BAX/view?usp=sharing). Any other suggestion? regards from Chile!

Comment: I'm going to spend some more time on this today. I'll come back later.

Comment: Thanks Cooper, I really apreciate your help.

Comment: Cooper, thanks for your time.Changing the format on the A column solve the xlabel issue, but the chart looks deformed [Look](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jCxtJp1R0449RS4s4CmGURyPrvVVdAWg/view?usp=sharing).  I'm trying a new strategy, using unixtime format date on the column, and later try to replace the value on horizontal axis with a literal string as the [line chart documentatión](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) shows on the 'hAxis.ticks' option. I will edit the original post to include some code and details of the new error I got with this option.